# Android notificationcompat sound/vibration not working

Tags: android

I've spent my last 2 hours trying to figure our why my notification sent from FireBase doesn't make any sound or vibration.

I have looked on many topics about this problem and tried different combinations with `.setDefaults` `.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })` `.setSound(defaultSoundUri)`

What I have right now is this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(-1)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

I don't have any errors and the notification is showing but I repeat, no sound, no vibration, no led lights, no heads-up.

To send the notification I use a python library on my server:

```
# Send to single device.
from pyfcm import FCMNotification

push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

registration_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
message_title = "Test"
message_body = "Test notification"
result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)

print result
```

Note: I already have in manifest defined permission:     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`
Any ideea ?

Comment: If you are sending via app server then please share your notification payload in json

Comment: Just remove .setDefaults(-1) and use .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND) instead

Comment: @NishantDubey I added the code from my server. Jai removing .setDefaults(-1) doesn't work

Comment: @PavelMarian : Hope you added permission for VIBRATE in manifest and .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND) added this?

Comment: @Jai I already have that defined in manifest and with .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND) doesn't work already tried :(

Answer (score 2):

**You aren't sending sound flag from your server** maybe that's why you aren't getting notification sound. Please try adding:

```
sound = "default"
```

This will probably get you the sound of notification.

Have a look at this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

for better understanding of fcm downstream android notification flags.

Do let me know if it changes anything for you.

Comment: Ok, the problem with the sound was solved, but why no vibration and heads-up ?

Comment: Please have a look at the link. You also need to set **priority** As **high** from server

Comment: consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Priority is set as high by default on my server.

Answer (score 1):

For having ability to use sound and vibrate check if you had the right premission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: what phone you used?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy s6

Comment: check that you didnt block the sound and notification for your app via Samsung site :
http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/skp/FAQ/1077072